# Copy files from SFTP server to HDFS using Nifi

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm trying to load huge data consisting of 225 GB (no. of file ~1,75,000) from SFTP server and copying data to HDFS.

To implement above scenario we've used 2 processors.

1. GetSFTP (To get the files from SFTP server)

Configured Processor -> serach recursively = true ; use Natural Ordering = true ; Remote Poll Batch Size = 5000; concurrent tasks = 3

2.PutHDFS (Pushing the data to HDFS)

Configured Processor -> concurrent tasks = 3; Confict Resolution Strategy = replace ; Hadoop Configuration Resources; Directory

But after some time data copying is getting stopped and it's size is not updating in HDFS.
When i set Remote Poll Batch Size in GetSFTP configure settings to 5000 -> total data pushed to HDFS is 6.4 GB, When set to 20000 -> total data pushed to HDFS is 25 GB

But I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have **`scheduled GetSFTP processor`** to run based on Timer Drivern (or) Cron Driven.

Ideal solution will be Using **`ListSFTP + FetchSFTP`** processors instead of `GetSFTP` processor.

Refer [this](https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/23/listfetch-pattern-and-remote-process-group-in-apache-nifi/) link for configuring/usage of List+Fetch sftp processors.

Comment: Thanks @Shu, for ur response.
We have also used (ListSFTP + FetchSFTP processors ), but  ListSFTP is taking more than 40 min just to do a file listing as there are 225 GB data need to be transferred. So, What can we do to decrease a file listing time using ListSFTP ?

Comment: @Deepanshu try to increase number of concurrent tasks in List and fetch processors..!!

Comment: In listSFTP how can we increase the concurrent tasks value becoz in listSFTP, we can't edit the listSFTP concurrent tasks value and also we have increase the fetchSFTP concurrent task value to 10.